# Setting date range in DynamicTimeSeriesCollection horizontal axis

Tags: jfreechart

I am now working on a `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection` chart which display energy value in Y-axis, and X-axis should be date.

```
 private final Second time = new Second();
 private final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, 180, time);
```

The JFreeChart display a tick every 1/2 second automatically as the following example!

```
00:13:00
00:13:30
00:14:00
00:14:30
```

How can I change them by my customized value as:

```
00:13:00---> 01-Jan-2011
00:13:30---> 02-Jan-2011
00:14:00---> 03-Jan-2011
00:14:30---> 04-Jan-2011
```

(1 default second = 2 days in my case).

I can't find any solution, could any one help?

Comment: Why are you using Seconds and not [Days](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/Day.html)?

Comment: My chart will display all data of a year (365 days) in 3 minutes. It means 1 second = 2 days. 
If i use Days it will update secondly or not ? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Finally i resolved my question by using TimeSeries. We can create a dataset as we need:

```
    TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("L&G European Index Trust");

    s1.add(new Day(1, 1, 2001), 181.8);       
    s1.add(new Day(3, 1, 2001), 181.8);
    s1.add(new Day(5, 1, 2001), 167.3);
    s1.add(new Day(7, 1, 2001), 153.8);
```

In TimeSeries we can control dataset, i means value and date better than DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.